# Sum the first element of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a list of the following:

`list={{1,2},{1,6.5},{1,6},{1,0}....{1,36}}`.

Let say the Length of the list is 300. I would like to sum the first member of the first case of the list by 0. The first member of the second case by 1. The first member of the third case by 2 and so on. The result would be the following:

```
{{1,2},{2,6.5},{3,6},{4,0},...{300,36}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list = {{1, 2}, {1, 6.5}, {1, 6}, {1, 0}, {1, 36}};

add = Transpose[{Range@# - 1, Array[0 &, #]}] &[Length@list]
```

> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}}

```
list + add
```

> {{1, 2}, {2, 6.5}, {3, 6}, {4, 0}, {5, 36}}

Or

```
ReplacePart[list, i_ :> {list[[i, 1]] + i - 1, list[[i, 2]]}]
```

> {{1, 2}, {2, 6.5}, {3, 6}, {4, 0}, {5, 36}}

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
MapIndexed[{First@#2 - 1, 0} + #1 &, list]
```

Comment: `MapIndexed[#1 + Append[#2 - 1, 0] &, list]` is also a possibility.

Answer (score 3):

```
list[[All, 1]] = list[[All, 1]] + Range[0, Length[list] - 1];
list
```

Answer (score 3):

[`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html), which seems to often slip under the radar on this site, can be used to solve this problem.

```
data = {{1, 2}, {1, 6.5}, {1, 6}, {1, 0}, {1, 36}};
Transpose[MapAt[Accumulate, Transpose[data], 1]]
```

> `{{1, 2}, {2, 6.5}, {3, 6}, {4, 0}, {5, 36}}`

Comment: +1 for using Accumulate, because that helped me solve a similar problem: I wanted to accumulate the second element of each tuple in a list of pairs. Or, even accumulate a list, then combine the list with another list to create the pairs since I know how to do that.... So thanks for exposing this part of the API, Accumulate, to us on SE.